# Map a file and get byte value

Tags: c, io, mmap

I need to map a file and then get it's byte value (from the mapped region).

I've map the file, like so:

```
void* kd_test_mmapw( int d, int size )
{
    void *a = NULL;
    a = mmap( NULL, size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, d, 0 );
    if( a == MAP_FAILED )
    {
        perror( "mmap failed" );
        abort();
    }
    return a;
}
```

But I have no idea how to get the byte value

Comment: a  is a pointer to the first byte of the file.  you will need to cast it and then dereference it.

Comment: Be very, very careful here.  You are passing in a signed integer and using that signed integer for a memory allocation.  It's excellent that you are checking for an error after the mmap, but a negative number in there may not fail; it may inadvertently allocate way more memory than you intended!

Comment: What about RTFM (`man mmap`)? At least on Linux there is a nice example at the bottom of the man-page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is a pointer to the first byte of you mapped region. You can consider your pointer as a pointer to an array of bytes.

If you want to access the `1234` bytes, just use:

```
char *asChar = (char*)a;
char myByte = asChar[1233];
```